# How do i pass a boolean into a new object?

Tags: java, object, constructor, boolean

```
public class Clown {
    boolean standing = false;

    public Clown(boolean standing) { 
        Clown clown = new Clown(standing);
    }
```

I want to make a new Clown object with the boolean passed in but everytime I run this I get a stack overflow error. How can I fix this?

Comment: lametaweb's solution is correct. If you're wondering why you are getting a stack overflow exception, consider that each time you call `Clown(boolean)`, it in turn calls itself.

Answer (score 4):

You obtain a `StackOverflow` `Exception` because you are doing a "recursive" call when you invoke the constructor from itself.

Do:

```
public class Clown {

  boolean standing;

  public Clown(boolean standing) {
      this.standing  = standing;
  }
```

Then create the `Object` from some method of some class with:

```
Clown clown = new Clown(standing);
```

Comment: create the object __outside the constructor__ --obviously OP missed that; it might be an important highlight